# OS X/Cocoa: How to redraw mouse NSCursor while dragging mouse mouseDragged: (NSEvent)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to redraw mouse cursor while I am dragging the mouse. 
So I have implemented `mouseDragged: (NSEvent)` method. Than I am calling method that updates cursor `resetCursorRects`. In this method I am drawing new `NSImage` based on which I will create new custom cursor `NSCursor`. Than I am adding this new cursor to display. But it isn't displayed while dragging. Analogical approach while I am just moving the mouse 
`mouseMoved: (NSEvent)` updated (redraw cursor correctly).

Code:

```
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

    // create path for the shape layer
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, self.startPoint.x, self.startPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, self.startPoint.x, point.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, self.startPoint.y);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    // set the shape layer's path
    self.shapeLayer.path = path;

    CGPathRelease(path);

    // update cursor while dragging with new position
    self.mousePosition = point;
    [self resetCursorRects];

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
    [self displayIfNeeded];
}

- (void)resetCursorRects
{
    [super resetCursorRects];
    [self discardCursorRects];

    __weak SelectionView *weakSelf = self;

    //NSLog(@"Mouse position: (%f, %f).\n", self.mousePosition.x, self.mousePosition.y);

    cursorImage = [NSImage imageWithSize: NSMakeSize(100.0, 100.0)
                                 flipped:YES
                          drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {

                              NSLog(@"LOL\n");

                            [crosshairCursorImage drawInRect: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];

                              NSMutableParagraphStyle* textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle.mutableCopy;
                              textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                              NSDictionary* textFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 10], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor darkGrayColor], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle};

                              NSString *xMousePos = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int) weakSelf.mousePosition.x];
                              NSString *yMousePos = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int) (weakSelf.bounds.size.height - weakSelf.mousePosition.y)];

                              [xMousePos drawInRect: CGRectMake(15.0, 10.0, 25.0, 20.0) withAttributes: textFontAttributes];
                              [yMousePos drawInRect: CGRectMake(15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 20.0) withAttributes: textFontAttributes];

                              return YES;
                          }];

    customCursor = [[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage: cursorImage hotSpot: NSMakePoint(10.0f,10.0f)];


    [self  addCursorRect: self.bounds cursor: customCursor];
}
```

Logs:

```
2016-09-21 13:50:28.153 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.153 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.154 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (234.882812, 347.257812).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.154 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.154 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.361 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (232.789062, 348.304688).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.362 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.362 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.362 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (232.789062, 348.304688).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.362 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.363 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.380 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (224.414062, 353.539062).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.380 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.380 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.381 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (224.414062, 353.539062).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.381 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.381 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.397 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (212.898438, 359.820312).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.397 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.398 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.398 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (212.898438, 359.820312).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.398 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.398 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.413 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (200.335938, 364.007812).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.413 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.413 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.430 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (186.726562, 367.148438).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.430 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.430 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.449 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (175.210938, 369.242188).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.449 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.449 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.465 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (168.929688, 369.937500).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.465 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.465 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.482 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (163.695312, 370.984375).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.482 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.482 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.499 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (159.507812, 372.031250).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.500 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.500 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.517 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (156.367188, 373.078125).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.517 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.518 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.533 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (154.273438, 373.078125).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.533 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.533 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.551 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (153.226562, 373.078125).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.551 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.551 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.568 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (152.179688, 373.078125).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.568 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.568 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.586 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (150.785156, 373.078125).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.586 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.586 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.713 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (150.085938, 373.078125).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.713 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.713 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.746 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (149.386719, 373.078125).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.747 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.747 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.763 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (148.339844, 375.171875).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.763 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.763 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.781 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (148.339844, 376.218750).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.782 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.782 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.799 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (146.246094, 377.265625).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.799 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.800 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.816 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (146.246094, 378.312500).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.817 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.817 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.834 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (145.199219, 379.359375).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.835 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.835 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.849 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (145.199219, 380.359375).
2016-09-21 13:50:28.850 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:28.850 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.256 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (144.503906, 380.359375).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.256 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.256 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.272 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (142.410156, 381.406250).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.272 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.273 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.289 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (141.363281, 382.453125).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.289 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.290 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.307 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (137.175781, 385.593750).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.308 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.308 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.326 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (129.847656, 390.828125).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.326 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.326 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.342 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (124.613281, 396.062500).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.343 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.343 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.358 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (119.378906, 399.203125).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.358 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.358 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.375 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (115.191406, 402.695312).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.376 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.376 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.392 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (112.050781, 404.789062).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.393 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.393 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.410 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (108.910156, 407.929688).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.410 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.410 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.428 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (107.863281, 408.976562).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.428 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.428 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.446 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (104.722656, 410.023438).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.447 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.447 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.462 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (103.675781, 412.117188).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.462 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.462 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.480 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (102.976562, 413.511719).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.480 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.480 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.495 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (101.976562, 413.511719).
2016-09-21 13:50:29.496 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.496 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.565 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.565 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.587 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.588 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.601 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.601 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.618 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.618 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.637 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.637 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.653 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.654 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.669 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.669 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.686 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.686 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.704 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.704 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.721 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.721 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.737 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.737 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.754 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.754 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.771 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.771 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.787 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.788 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.804 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.804 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.821 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.821 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.838 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.838 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.855 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.856 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.872 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:29.872 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.095 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.095 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.113 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.113 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.130 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.130 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.147 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.147 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.164 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.164 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.182 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.182 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.199 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.199 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.216 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.217 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.234 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.234 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.251 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.252 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.269 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.269 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.290 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.290 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.306 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.306 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.322 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.322 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.339 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.339 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.356 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.357 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.373 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.373 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.390 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.391 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.408 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.408 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.424 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.424 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.441 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.441 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.457 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.457 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.474 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.474 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.491 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.491 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.647 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.647 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.672 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.672 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.935 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.935 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.952 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.952 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.984 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:30.984 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.496 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (484.382812, 139.980469).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.496 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.496 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.516 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (481.242188, 142.074219).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.517 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.517 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.532 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (472.867188, 147.308594).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.532 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.532 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.533 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (472.867188, 147.308594).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.533 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.533 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.549 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (458.210938, 155.683594).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.550 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.550 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.550 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (458.210938, 155.683594).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.550 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.550 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.564 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (436.226562, 168.246094).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.565 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.565 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.565 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (436.226562, 168.246094).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.565 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.565 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.583 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (400.632812, 190.226562).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.583 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.583 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.583 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (400.632812, 190.226562).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.583 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.583 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.600 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (366.085938, 215.351562).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.600 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.601 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.601 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (366.085938, 215.351562).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.601 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.601 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.617 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (338.871094, 236.289062).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.617 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.617 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.617 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (338.871094, 236.289062).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.618 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.618 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.633 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (306.066406, 259.320312).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.634 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.634 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.634 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (306.066406, 259.320312).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.634 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.634 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.651 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (280.941406, 278.164062).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.651 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.651 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.651 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (280.941406, 278.164062).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.652 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.652 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.668 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (255.820312, 295.960938).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.668 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.668 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.668 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (255.820312, 295.960938).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.668 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.669 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.685 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (243.257812, 307.476562).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.685 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.685 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.685 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (243.257812, 307.476562).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.686 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.686 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.702 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (221.273438, 329.460938).
2016-09-21 13:50:31.702 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before cursor image log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.703 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Before custom cursor log.
2016-09-21 13:50:31.703 SelectionView[8618:3964189] Mouse position: (221.273438, 329.460938).
```

Messages are printed I think that the problem can be with drawingHandler block object

```
^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) { // drawing }
```

I don't know why mouseDragged() regardless of it is also drawing or not blocks execution of NSCursor redrawing.

Now I consider reimplement this to just only change cursor image while on my custom NSView, and add another small custom view with cursor position that will be transparent and will follow the cursor position. But what if also this NSView want be changing position while mouseDragged() event happens.

Comment: Likely the handler isn't executed before the image is assigned. Please add an `NSLog()` before `customCursor = …` and paste the result of both logs to your Q.